# How to use D3 filter in paraview?

Tags: filter, grid, paraview

Does anyone faced an issue when using paraview with unstructured data ?

Basically, in paraview with incorrect point Data on the boundary, iso-contour surface are likely to have rips or holes along the parallel partition boundary making them topologically incorrect.

I did some research, and I ended up that using the filter D3 in paraview allows to construct the missing ghost cells and solve the problem.

I tried to use that in paraview but still not working. I am wondering if someone has used the filter D3 to help understand the method?

For me, creating directly Filter D3 from my data does not allows to obtain the contour. So I used instead the filter CellDatatoPointData and then I construct the contour( it  contains holes), and to fix these holes, I applied D3 filter to the contour by choosing in D3 properties: minimum number of ghost levels = 2 (also tried 1) and boundary mode, I tried all the options (assign cells uniquely, duplicate cells, divide cells.

It is still not working. I also had the following output error message in paraview: ERROR: In /opt/glr/paraview/paraview-ci/build/superbuild/paraview/src/VTK/Common/DataModel/vtkKdTree.cxx, line 773
vtkPKdTree (0x7fea83ed9a80): vtkKdTree::BuildLocator - No cells to subdivide

Comment: Share your data.

Comment: What do you mean by `incorrect point Data` ? Incorrect input often leads to incorrect output ... You may also try `GhostCellGenerator` instead of D3

Comment: GhostCellGenerator is not available in my case.

Comment: I mean when I upload a data file in paraview, this file contains ghost cells, when I do filter (using cellDatatoPointData), the ghost cell are not taken into account, that what I call it incorrect point data. The input is correct when I upload it, but the filter used like cell datatopointdata does not read the ghost cell, which make the data incorrect for treatment. This leads to incorrect representation like holes and rips.